# Only one build version in nextJS 13 - Environmental variables

Tags: next.js, build, continuous-integration, environment-variables, next.js13

I am building a new project in nextJS 13 and I am facing an issue with the build version.

I have 5 different env files with a lot of variables, some of them are the REST endpoints I use in the app.

At building time, next generates static files and replaces the env variables. I do not want that, I need the same build version for all of my environments.

What alternatives do I have for this?

The main problem for me are the different REST endpoints, should I use something different than env variables?

Comment: What are the names of your `env` files?

Comment: I have custom env yml files: local.yml, dev.yml, pre.yml, stg.yml and pro.yml

Comment: How did you integrate the yml files with Next.js?

Comment: With dotenv-yaml, I updated it to NextJS14 and now it is not working though